# Koth of the Hammer (-2 ability)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Will the mana that has been added to your mana pool by [Koth of the Hammer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKoth%20of%20the%20Hammer%5d)'s -2 ability empty as your turn ends, or is the mana from the -2 ability added for the rest of the game?

Answer (score 1):

Mana empties from every player's mana pool at the end of each step and phase.

> 500.4. When a step or phase ends, any unused mana left in a player’s mana pool empties. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.